# What happened to the passport of Prince Charles when he became King Charles III?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy, identity-document

Queen Elizabeth II (of the UK and other assorted Commonwealth realms) somewhat famously did not have a passport. (The theory being that passports are technically issued in the Monarch's name, so it would have been superfluous/nonsensical for her to issue one to herself.) However, all other members of the royal family are issued passports.

What happened to Charles's passport once he became King?

I fully realize that as King, Charles does not *need* a passport, and in practice he would not use one for any future international trips. What I'm asking about instead is the formal validity of his existing passport. Is the passport that was issued to Charles, Prince of Wales, still technically a valid document, or was it officially voided upon his ascension?

I'd also be interested in any other documents (e.g. driver's license) which the Monarch is not issued, but which the Prince of Wales would have been. Also, while I've tagged this as UK, I'm asking generally about any/all of the Commonwealth realms, especially to the extent the answer is different.

Comment: Presumably, all of Prince Charles' travel documents become nullified (by means of redundancy) when he becomes King Charles. I suppose the custom *can* request the King to present a passport, but it wouldn't be necessary since he is King, but also the passport would not be valid anyway since "Prince Charles" no longer exists, if that makes sense.

Comment: If we think about it in administrative terms, Prince Charles' documents would become invalid upon him becoming King, the same way a person's document becomes invalid when they die or change their legal gender (i.e. replacing it with new documents).

Comment: @QuantumWalnut They would not become invalid unless there are regulations somewhere that *say* they become invalid (possibly indirectly). When you change your gender your old passport isn't valid because one of the pieces of information a passport contains **is** your gender. You no longer match your identity document, so the regulations say agencies should not accept it as verifying your identity. What we're looking for here is whether a change in noble **title** invalidates passports. If it was issued to "Charles of the house of Windsor" rather than "Prince Charles", then that still matches.

Comment: I think it's rather likely that there are no regulations that cover this case because there was never any pressing *need* to know whether a passport issued to the monarch before they were the monarch is still valid. It can only come up once a generation (on average), and if the monarch doesn't need a passport anyway then it does no good or harm whatever the answer is. So the people writing the regulation may have simply not bothered to answer the question (or completely missed that there was a question).

Comment: I suppose whether Charles needs a passport depends on whether he travels in his official capacity as a King or as a private citizen. This is probably the same as distinction between conventional passports and [*diplomatic passports*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport#Diplomatic_and_official_passports). Peter I of Russia had famously traveled to Europe "incognito" to observe European customs without being burdened by too much formalities - if it happened today, he would need a passport.

Comment: Charles has a lot of courtiers who will take care of this. Regardless, I doubt there is a formal procedure, so this question depends on speculation. Whether it sits in a drawer (or probably a safe) or is returned to the passport office doesn't really matter.

Comment: @RogerVadim Charles isn't a private citizen; he is the head of state (of several countries, no less). He can't travel in a private capacity unless he abdicates.  For example, the US requires heads of state and government to travel in A-1 status regardless of the purpose of their trip.  Other government officials and diplomats have A-1 status only if they're traveling for an official purpose.  Though it's true that Charles would need a passport if he wanted to travel incognito.

Comment: How is this a politics question at all? This looks like a matter of mere legal technicality.

Comment: People are talking about "regulations" and "legal technicality": the issue and validity of British passports is not governed by any law or regulations, it's at the absolute discretion of the Home Secretary under a Royal Prerogative power.  See <https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN06820/SN06820.pdf#page=12>

Comment: Does the Home Secretary realistically have any power or motive to prevent Charles III from travelling internationally? No. So the question of his passport is mere matter of legal ceremony: it has no material influence on anyone’s ability to take action or make decisions.

Comment: Why would anything have to happen to it? If he doesn't need it any more, he just leaves it wherever he's been keeping it. I suppose it could be sent to a museum as a royal artifact.

Comment: His previous passport was technically owned by his mother, so... he inherits it? :-)